# Spark: get distinct in each partition

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to partition data using ID, and with in each partition I want to

-apply a set of operations

-take distinct

Doing distinct within each partition will avoid shuffling.

```
val rowRDD = sc.textFile("flatten_test_data")
    .filter(_.nonEmpty)
    .map { l =>
        val arr = l.split("\u0001")
        val id = arr(0)
         val value = arr(1)
         (id,value)
    }.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(4))
    .persist()
```

Now do something like--

```
rowRDD.foreachPartition {records => applyOpers(records)}
```

applyOpers(dataset) should do something like-

```
dataset.withColumn(udf1).withColumn(udf2).distinct
```

Comment: you cannot use spark code (datasets, udfs etc) within `foreachPartition`

Answer (score 1):

`forEachPartition` gets executed on the executor. Hence, you cannot access SparkContext/SparkSession inside a forEachPartition.

You can use `mapPartitions()` as an alternative to `map()` & `foreach()`. `mapPartitions()` is called once for each Partition unlike `map()` & `foreach()` which is called for each element in the RDD. The main advantage being that, we can do initialization on Per-Partition basis instead of per-element basis.

We get `Iterator` as an argument for `mapPartition`, through which we can iterate through all the elements in a Partition.

For example: (The example is in java but this should give you an idea.)

```
JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = sc.parallelize(
      Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    FlatMapFunction<Iterator<Integer>, AvgCount> setup = new FlatMapFunction<Iterator<Integer>, AvgCount>() {
      @Override
      public Iterable<AvgCount> call(Iterator<Integer> input) {
        AvgCount a = new AvgCount(0, 0);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
          a.total_ += input.next();
          a.num_ += 1;
        }
        ArrayList<AvgCount> ret = new ArrayList<AvgCount>();
        ret.add(a);
        return ret;
      }
    };
    Function2<AvgCount, AvgCount, AvgCount> combine = new Function2<AvgCount, AvgCount, AvgCount>() {
        @Override
        public AvgCount call(AvgCount a, AvgCount b) {
        a.total_ += b.total_;
        a.num_ += b.num_;
        return a;
        }
    };

AvgCount result = rdd.mapPartitions(setup).reduce(combine);
```